# Enlarge footnotesep without adding space above footnotes?

Tags: footnotes

I need to make my footnotes have extra space between them; however, manipulating `footnotesep` adds extra space above the footnotes. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Here is some text\footnote{A footnote} with some footnotes\footnote{Another!}.

\clearpage

\setlength{\footnotesep}{2\baselineskip}
Here is some text\footnote{A footnote} with some footnotes\footnote{Another!} and too much space.

\end{document}
```

Normal spacing above:
[image]

Undesirable spacing above:
[image]

Comment: in `latex.ltx`, the footnote text is defined to start with an invisible rule (to "freeze" the vertical position) followed by `\footnotesep`.  to disable the space between the footnote rule and the first footnote on a page, one way would be to patch that definition to test whether this is the first footnote and use a smaller value for `\footnotesep` if that is true.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Can you give an example of how this would work?

Comment: it's not straightforward, and involves tinkering with the innards of latex.  i don't have time right now (i estimate it to take a couple of hours to test it thoroughly) but i'll try to come back to it later.

Comment: One other idea (not tested): could one hack `\footnoterule` to insert some negative vertical space. It's defined to take 0 space ... if it took less than zero then it would pull the resulting footnote up ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on my comment, because it *seems* to work on superficial testing.

Define a macro to lift footnotes:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\liftfootnotes}[1]{%
\def\footnoterule{\kern-3\p@ \hrule \@width 2in \kern -#1}}
\makeatother
```

After redefining `\footnotesep`, "lift footnotes". You need to experiment with the exact amount, but `1.2\baselineskip` seems about right

```
\liftfootnotes{1.2\baselineskip}
```

Comment: This makes the footnoterule occupy (negative) space which confuses the LaTeX page breaking algorithm: If you add enough text to fill a page, you see that the page with the footnotes is about `1.2\baselineskip` shorter than a normal page.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid problems with shorter pages when using footnotes, `\skip\footins` has to be adjusted in addition to Paul Stanleys `\liftfootnotes`. This can be done with

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\liftfootnotes}[1]{%
  \advance\skip\footins by-#1%
  \def\footnoterule{\kern#1\kern-3\p@ \hrule \@width 2in \kern-#1}}
\makeatother
```

Then use something like

```
\liftfootnotes{1.2\baselineskip}
```

to specify how much to lift the footnotes.

Comment: +1 That's better. I felt sure it was more difficult than I had imagined!